# Python Code to Parse & Retrieve value from URL string

Tags: python, parsing, url

I have some Dot Net code that parses and retrieves a value from a URL string.

However, I would like to perform the same function but now use python code instead.

Dot Net code snippet is below:

```
string queryString = string.Empty;
string application_id = string.Empty;
string currentURL = Browser.getDriver.Url;
Uri url = new Uri(currentURL);
string query_String = url.Query;
application_id = query_String.Split(new char[] { '=' }).Last();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We would need more information, will you run your code from within a web-framework as `Django` or `Flask`?. Because the last line of your code is almost the same on Python, so I'm assuming that you want the whole funcionality in python: from retrieving URL to strip the id of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always best to use std lib functions if they are available. Python 3 has `urllib.parse` (if you are still on Py2, it's `urlparse`). Use the `urlparse` method of this module to extract the query part of the url (the stuff after the '?'). Then `parse_qs` will convert this query to a dict of `key:list` values - the values are lists to handle query strings that have repeated keys.

```
url = 'http://www.somesite.blah/page?id=12345&attr=good&attr=bad&attr=ugly'

try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
except ImportError:
    # still using Python 2? time to move up
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

parts = urlparse(url)
print(parts)
query_dict = parse_qs(parts.query)
print(query_dict)
print(query_dict['id'][0])
```

prints:

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.somesite.blah', path='/page', params='', 
            query='id=12345&attr=good&attr=bad&attr=ugly', fragment='')

{'attr': ['good', 'bad', 'ugly'], 'id': ['12345']}
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

first, last = query_String.split('=')

Comment: Will give an error if there is more than one parameter in the query string (as in `"size=large&color=blue"`).